# SQL Server: Select in vs or?

Tags: sql-server, performance, inline

Which is faster?

```
SELECT UserName
FROM dbo.UserTable
WHERE UserID in (1,3,4)
```

---

```
SELECT UserName
FROM dbo.UserTable
WHERE UserID = 1 
      OR UserID = 3
      OR UserID = 4
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3074713/in-vs-or-in-the-sql-where-clause

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Due to Sql Server's optimization of queries these will run at the same speed since they are logically equivalent.

i favor the IN syntax for brevity and readability though.

Comment: Rather then Or/In is there any way to query? that will perform faster?

Comment: @Worgon if the number of values is large you could put the distinct values into an indexed temp table and join on that.

Answer (score 8):

Actually it is the same.

If you display the estimated execution plan you will see that it is performing the same action.

Answer (score -1):

This is relevant when it comes to producing SQL via Linq. There are some instances where the sql created is in the form of: field='xxx' OR field='yyy'.

Comment: Can you please clarify that? I have no idea what you are saying.