# jdbc mysql batch prepared call keeps only the last result set

Tags: mysql, select, jdbc, prepared-statement

I have a stored procedure call

```
call get(id);
```

in my database that would return a single row in a ResultSet object (it is basically a very long SELECT statement inside). Now in Java, I have a

```
int[] ids = {1,2,3}
```

and **for each id in the list I want to call the stored procedure to get the record**. So eventually I want a list of records corresponding to each id in ids. I attempted

```
Connection conn = ...;
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareCall("call get(?)");
for(int id : ids) {
    ps.setInt(1, id); ps.addBatch();
}
ps.executeBatch();
```

with only the result of call

```
get(3);
```

is kept.

I also tried to move the SELECT statement directly as a String in Java, so it looks like

```
String stmt = "SELECT ... WHERE id=?"
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(stmt);
... // the for loop same as above
ps.executeBatch();
```

with a "Can not issue executeUpdate() for SELECTs". I tried

```
ps.executeQuery();
```

as the last line, but it also only has the result of the last SELECT.

I want to avoid a for loop that executes a SELECT a time because transferring data from the database to my computer has a very heavy overhead.

Can anyone help? Thank you in advance!

EDIT: I read [Running the same select query multiple times with different parameters: Mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15841754/running-the-same-select-query-multiple-times-with-different-parameters-mysql?rq=1) , but in my case it is a little bit different, because in my select statement the id actually needs to be referenced several times; the code looks like this

```
SELECT * FROM
  (SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE id=? AND ...),
  (SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE id=? AND ...);
```

so it seems impractical to use the IN method. Also I have another call

```
call get2(aid, userId)
```

and a list of {{1, 1000}, {2, 2000}} which also does not fit this issue. Can anyone help? Thank you!

Comment: Execute batch is only for updates (and inserts, deletes), not for queries that return result sets.

Comment: Yeah I also noticed that...