# Does long query string affect the speed?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, optimization

Suppose i have a long query string for eg.

```
SELECT id from users where collegeid='1' or collegeid='2' . . . collegeid='1000'
```

will it affect the speed or output in any way?

```
SELECT m.id,m.message,m.postby,m.tstamp,m.type,m.category,u.name,u.img 
from messages m 
join users u on m.postby=u.uid 
where m.cid = '1' or m.cid  = '1' . . . . . . 
or m.cid = '1000'. . . .
```

Comment: Not sure about the speed but why do you not just use collegeid IN (1,2,3..) etc.  Saves a lot of typing!

Comment: please be specific..There are many factors to consider: memory,dbms,joins,index Key....

Comment: @Andrew can i have 1000 entries in IN?

Comment: @Anirudh yep i'm dealing with joins

Comment: I don't see why not.  In LINQ you have a limitation of 2100 or thereabouts when using Contains and that is converted (I think) to an IN statement.

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/1584e0b0-4b04-403d-8766-a7c73f473ecd/max-number-of-elements-allowed-in-an-in-clause?forum=transactsql

Comment: @user2894116 please post your exact query..

Comment: What RDBMS you are using? SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle, etc ...??

Comment: @Anirudh posted my original query

Comment: @MahmoudGamal i'm using Mysql

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would prefer to use `IN` in this case as it would be better. However to check the performance you may try to look at the Execution Plan of the query which you are executing. You will get the idea about what performance difference you will get by using the both.

Something like this:

```
SELECT id from users where collegeid IN ('1','2','3'....,'1000')
```

According to the [MYSQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in)

> If all values are constants, they are evaluated according to the type
>   of expr and sorted. The search for the item then is done using a
>   binary search. **This means IN is very quick if the IN value list
>   consists entirely of constants.**
>
> The number of values in the IN list is only limited by the
>   **[max_allowed_packet](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet)** value.

You may also check [IN vs OR in the SQL WHERE Clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3074713/in-vs-or-in-the-sql-where-clause) and **[MYSQL OR vs IN performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/782915/mysql-or-vs-in-performance)**

The answer given by Ergec is very useful:

```
SELECT * FROM item WHERE id = 1 OR id = 2 ... id = 10000
```

This query took **0.1239 seconds**

```
SELECT * FROM item WHERE id IN (1,2,3,...10000)
```

This query took **0.0433 seconds**

## IN is 3 times faster than OR

> **will it affect the speed or output in any way?**

So the answer is **Yes** the performance will be affected.

Comment: There won't be any performance gain if those columns are indexed..There won't be any significant gain in performance even if they aren't indexed

Comment: @Anirudh: I don't think this claim holds in gneneral. Some DBMS will use an index even if if there is a disjunction / IN sublist in your where clause.

Comment: @Rahul Is there any limit on ids `In` can hold?

Comment: I would say that in that exact example 'IN' keyword is not the best answer either.  I would use BETWEEN 1 AND 1000

Comment: @user2894116:- Yes you can set it by the max_allowed_packet:- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet

Comment: @Ran That would help if id's are in continuation. But in my query there are chances that ids may be like this 5,8,9

Answer (score 2):

Obviously, there is no direct correlation between the length of a query string and its processing time (as some very short query can be tremendeously complex and vice versa). For your specific example: It depends on how the query is processed. This is something you can check by looking at the query execution plan (syntax depends on your DBMS, something like EXPLAIN PLAN). If the DBMS has to perform a full table scan, performance will only be affected slightly, since the DBMS has to visit all pages that make up the table anyhow. If there is an index on collegeid, performance will likely suffer more the more entries you put into your disjunction, since there will be several (though very fast) index lookups. At some point, there will we an full index scan instead of individual lookups, at which point performance will not degrade significantly anymore.

However - details depend ony our DBMS and its execution planner.

Answer (score 2):

I' not sure  you  are facing what I suffered.

Actually, string length is not problem. How many values are in IN() is more important.

I've tested how many elements can be listed IN().
Result is 10,000 elements can be processed without performance loss.

Values in IN() should be stored in somewhere and searched while query evaluation. But 10k values is getting slower.

So if you  have many 100k values, split 10 groups and try 10 times query. Or save in temp table and JOIN.

and long query uses more CPU, So IN() better than column = 1 OR  ...

Comment: my ids wont be more than 20k . Will it create problems?

Comment: It depends on your hardware. 20k won't be problem recently server. But you need to test your own test bed