# php/mySQL: querying records by id from array?

Tags: php, mysql

i want to query several records by id like:

```
$ids = array(10,12,14,16,....);
```

the query would be something like:

```
select * from users where id=10 or id=12 or id=14 or id=16 ..
```

is it possible to query it in a more comfortable way like (compared to php):

```
select * from user where in_array(id, array(10,12,14,16))
```

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use `IN` instead of `OR clauses`

```
select * from users where id IN (put_your_array_here)
```

**Example:**

```
select * from users where id IN (10,12,14,16);
```

**Note:**

> According to the [manual for MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in) if the values are constant `IN`
>   sorts the list and then uses a binary search. I would imagine that
>   `OR` evaluates them one by one in no particular order. So `IN` is
>   faster in some circumstances.

[**Related post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3074713/in-vs-or-in-the-sql-where-clause)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$id = array(10,12,14,16,....);

$ids = join("','",$id);
$sql =  "select * from user where id IN ('$ids')";
```

OR

```
$ids = implode(',', $id);
$sql =  "select * from user where id IN ($ids)";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like that using [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) in PHP:

```
"select * from users where id in '".implode("','", $ids)."'"
```

Please be sure [that your ids are safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1) though