# Cost difference between 'WHERE A=x' and 'WHERE A IN (x)'?

Tags: sqlite, where-in

If I want to find records where a given field is equal to some value, I use

```
SELECT * from TableName WHERE FieldName=value;
```

If I want to select records which match a list of values, I can use

```
SELECT * from TableName WHERE FieldName IN (value1, value2, ..., valueN);
```

<s>to avoid having `WHERE FieldName = value1 OR FieldName = value2 OR...`</s>
*(edited since seemingly this misled about the purpose of the question)*

Using `.eqp on` seems to suggest that when my list contains only one element, the two queries are equivalent.

Is this true?

If so, can I freely use `WHERE FieldName IN (...)` and parse values into a comma separated list (avoiding trailing commas, etc) without cost to the query?

It would seem this will greatly simplify coding my queries, but I am surprised that there isn't an additional complexity cost from the `IN` operator, regardless of the list being only one element.

**Edit**: To be clear, I won't use `OR` in any case - if I have one value, then previously I had been using the first form (`FieldName=value`). If I had several values, I used `IN (val1, val2, ...)`. Based on comments, it would seem that I can remove the code I need to use to handle these, and instead search only for `IN (value1)`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IN vs OR in the SQL WHERE Clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3074713/in-vs-or-in-the-sql-where-clause)

Comment: The information given in the answers there is useful, but the question is different.

Comment: No, I disagree, it is the same question.

Comment: But my question doesn't want to know about costs of IN vs OR. I want to know about the query in the title - `IN (x)` vs `=x` where x is a single value.

Comment: For a single value, there should not be any difference AFAIK.

Comment: Thanks. Perhaps discussing `OR` in the question was misleading. Certainly it seems that SO thinks I wanted to know about `IN` vs `OR` - unless that is because of the close vote as duplicate.

Comment: If you're worried about `IN` having a performance penalty with a single item versus `OR`, then this does not appear to be the case.  So you should be at an advantage using `IN` for single _or_ multiple items.

Comment: @muistooshort I mispoke, I must have been thinking of MariaDB or something else.  Bad on me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When SQLite estimates that the IN list is so short that its overhead is larger than that of an OR-connected series of equality comparisons, it converts the query into the latter form.
Currently, this is done for IN lists of size 1 or 2.

As shown by [EXPLAIN](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_explain.html), the code for a single item is identical:

```
sqlite> explain select * from t where x = 1;
addr  opcode         p1    p2    p3    p4             p5  comment      
----  -------------  ----  ----  ----  -------------  --  -------------
0     Init           0     10    0                    00  Start at 10  
1     OpenRead       0     2     0     1              00  root=2 iDb=0; t
2     Rewind         0     8     0                    00               
3       Column         0     0     1                    00  r[1]=t.x     
4       Ne             2     7     1     (BINARY)       51  if r[1]!=r[2] goto 7
5       Copy           1     3     0                    00  r[3]=r[1]    
6       ResultRow      3     1     0                    00  output=r[3]  
7     Next           0     3     0                    01               
8     Close          0     0     0                    00               
9     Halt           0     0     0                    00               
10    Transaction    0     0     1     0              01  usesStmtJournal=0
11    TableLock      0     2     0     t              00  iDb=0 root=2 write=0
12    Integer        1     2     0                    00  r[2]=1       
13    Goto           0     1     0                    00               
sqlite> explain select * from t where x in (1);
addr  opcode         p1    p2    p3    p4             p5  comment      
----  -------------  ----  ----  ----  -------------  --  -------------
0     Init           0     10    0                    00  Start at 10  
1     OpenRead       0     2     0     1              00  root=2 iDb=0; t
2     Rewind         0     8     0                    00               
3       Column         0     0     1                    00  r[1]=t.x     
4       Ne             2     7     1     (BINARY)       51  if r[1]!=r[2] goto 7
5       Copy           1     3     0                    00  r[3]=r[1]    
6       ResultRow      3     1     0                    00  output=r[3]  
7     Next           0     3     0                    01               
8     Close          0     0     0                    00               
9     Halt           0     0     0                    00               
10    Transaction    0     0     1     0              01  usesStmtJournal=0
11    TableLock      0     2     0     t              00  iDb=0 root=2 write=0
12    Integer        1     2     0                    00  r[2]=1       
13    Goto           0     1     0                    00
```

(SQLite also does the [opposite transformation](http://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html#or_opt) when you have too many OR terms.)