# JPA criteria API translates the 'in' expression to multiple 'OR'

Tags: java, jpa, openjpa

JPA criteria API with 'in' expression translates to multiple 'OR' instead of 'in'

e.g.

My primary model

```
public class Person {
    ...

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "department_id")
    private Department department;

    ...
}
```

many to one relationship

```
public class Department {
    @Id
    @Column(name="department_id")
    private Integer departmentId;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="department")
    private List<Person> person;

    ...
}
```

defined these two models in persistence.xml (Note: It doesn't specify any db dialect)

```
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
    version="2.1">

    <persistence-unit name="primary" transaction-type="JTA">

        <jta-data-source>java:openejb/Resource/jdbc/myDS</jta-data-source>

        <class>com.xyz.Person</class>
        <class>com.xyz.Department</class>
        ...

        <shared-cache-mode>ENABLE_SELECTIVE</shared-cache-mode>

        <properties>
            <property name="openjpa.Log" value="${open.jpa.log}" />
            <property name="openjpa.ConnectionFactoryProperties" value="printParameters=true" />
            <property name="openjpa.RuntimeUnenhancedClasses" value="unsupported" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

Following is the code with Criteria API to build the query:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Person> criteriaQuery = cb.createQuery(Person.class);
Root<Person> personRoot = criteriaQuery.from(Person.class);

criteriaQuery.select(personRoot);

List<Predicate> predicateList = new ArrayList<>();
predicateList.add(personRoot.get(Person_.department).get(Department_.departmentId).in(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3)));
// Using list because I actually need to add multiple conditions

criteriaQuery.where(predicateList.toArray(new Predicate[0]));

TypedQuery<Person> searchQuery = em.createQuery(criteriaQuery);

searchQuery.getResultList();
```

This prints the query in the following format:

```
SELECT t0.person_id, ... 
FROM person t0 
WHERE ((t0.department_id = ? OR t0.department_id = ? OR t0.department_id = ?) AND t0.department_id IS NOT NULL)
```

but what I supposed get is

```
SELECT t0.person_id, ... 
FROM person t0 
WHERE t0.department_id IN (?, ?, ?)
```

Env:

- Tomee 7.0.3
- Embedded OpenJPA
- Mariadb

Update:

I have also tried to add mariadb dialect as follows, but it doesn't help

```
<property name="openjpa.jdbc.DBDictionary" value="mariadb" />
```

Comment: maybe backend (dialect) has not 'in' ???. What real database is used?

Comment: it is mariadb. Mariadb supports 'in'

Comment: Try passing a `java.sql.Array` to the `in` - with SQL `"... in(?)"`.

Comment: Try specifying the "(1,2,3)" as a PARAMETER, and provide a List as the parameter value at runtime.

Comment: .in accepts either Object or Collection... Predicate in(Object... values);
or Predicate in(Collection<?> values);

Comment: `.in` accepts `Expression`. A `ParameterExpression` is an `Expression`.

Comment: unfortunately no luck :-(

Comment: In SQL an expression: `x IN (1, 2, 3)` is an equivalent of `x=1 or x=2 or x=3`, it gives exactly the same result. Why do you worry about it ? I personally wouln`t care of it.

Comment: yes functionally both are same, however there is some performance differences. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3074713/in-vs-or-in-the-sql-where-clause

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: I think you need to use

Predicate parentPredicate = parentExpression.in(predicateList);

Then apply the where clause

and last but not least something to order or group by, else you will have a ton of data. I can provide you a fully implemented example if you need but i think with the first line of code you can handle it

Answer (score 1):

The solution would be to use expression for example :

```
List<Long> departmentIdsList = new ArrayList();
departmentIdsList.add(1L);
departmentIdsList.add(2L);
departmentIdsList.add(3L);
Expression<Long> exp = personRoot.get("departmentId");//"departmentId" field name to be equated
predicateList.add(exp.in(departmentIdsList));
```

the above snippet should evaluate as in clause