# SQL server - Query optimization

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2

I would like to know from below queries, which one would give better performance and how?

```
select * from TableA where (Name = 'ABC' or Name = 'DEF' or Name = 'GHI')
```

or

```
select * from TableA where Name in ('ABC','DEF','GHI')
```

Comment: Already answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3074713/in-vs-or-in-the-sql-where-clause

Answer (score 1):

Internally both IN and OR operators perform the same action. More importantly you need to see if you have proper index on the Name column.You can have a non-clustered index on the Name column and have one clustered index on this table.