# SQL - where statement conditions

Tags: sql, where-clause, case-when

Below is my query, I am fairly new to sql so my understanding is not the best. I want my query results to only give me the names I specify within my 'where' statement. Below in my query there are 4 activity names, 1 team name, and 1 date range ( 3 different colums, the 4 activities are found in the column 'name'). It has to match all these conditions.

My query works up until the second name that I specify within my 'where' statement.

Query:

```
SELECT *

FROM databse1.dbo.table1

where team_name = 'CTM Tier 2'
        and date >= '2018-02-01' and date <= '2018-02-28'
        and name = 'Post Vet 460' 
        and name = 'Post Vet CA Complex'
        and name = 'Post Vet CA Standard'
        and name = 'Post Vet CAA'
```

There query runs fine up until (and name = 'Post Vet 460'), but if I run the query as a whole it gives me blank results. Am I supposed to use a case when statement in this situation, all suggestions and tips are greatly appreciated thanks!

Comment: It's generally a bad idea to use `case` _expressions_ in `where` (and `on`) clauses. Use `and`/`or` constructions instead.

Answer (score 3):

it can't be all those at once, so use the in operator

```
and name in ('Post Vet 460', 'Post Vet CA Complex', 'Post Vet CA Standard', 'Post Vet CAA')
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want `IN`:

```
select t1.*
from databse1.dbo.table1 t1
where team_name = 'CTM Tier 2' and
      date >= '2018-02-01' and date <= '2018-02-28' and
      name in ('Post Vet 460', 'Post Vet CA Complex', 'Post Vet CA Standard', 'Post Vet CAA');
```

Your query returns nothing, because `name` cannot have *different* values on the *same* row.

You might also want `like`, depending on what your data looks like:

```
select t1.*
from databse1.dbo.table1 t1
where team_name = 'CTM Tier 2' and
      date >= '2018-02-01' and date <= '2018-02-28' and
      name like 'Post Vet %'
```

Answer (score 0):

Now try this query !
you need to find any row having either one of these name .so need to use OR condition .

```
SELECT *

FROM databse1.dbo.table1

where team_name = 'CTM Tier 2'
        and date >= '2018-02-01' and date <= '2018-02-28'
        and 
        (   name = 'Post Vet 460' 
        or  name = 'Post Vet CA Complex'
        or  name = 'Post Vet CA Standard'
        or  name = 'Post Vet CAA'
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing is because you are using the `AND` operator.

You should use the `OR` operator, instead.

Here's the correct implementation:

```
WHERE team_name = 'CTM Tier 2'
        AND date >= '2018-02-01' AND date <= '2018-02-28'
        AND name = 'Post Vet 460' 
        OR name = 'Post Vet CA Complex'
        OR name = 'Post Vet CA Standard'
        OR name = 'Post Vet CAA'
```

As pointed out by others you can also use `IN`.

```
WHERE team_name = 'CTM Tier 2'
        AND date >= '2018-02-01' AND date <= '2018-02-28'
        AND name IN ('Post Vet 460', 'Post Vet CA Complex', 'Post Vet CA Standard', 'Post Vet CAA')
```

If you want to read more about `IN` and the differences with `OR`, [have a look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3074713/in-vs-or-in-the-sql-where-clause).