# Do SQL parsers just interpret IN as a series of OR conditions?

Tags: sql, database, algorithm, parsing, sql-parser

When writing an SQL query such as

```
SELECT ID, NAME FROM USER_TABLE WHERE ID IN (1, 2, 10, 14, 15, ..., n)
```

does the parser just rephrase that into this?

```
SELECT ID, NAME FROM USER_TABLE WHERE ID = 1 
                                      OR ID =  2 
                                      OR ID =  10
                                      OR ID =  14
                                      OR ID =  15 
                                      ...
                                      OR ID =  n
```

Or does it do something else in the background for efficiency? While a nightmare to write out by hand and I would never advocate doing so, is there any theoretical performance benefit or hit to using IN rather than a series of OR conditions like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the specs ([SQL92 for example](https://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt)), `x IN (a, b, c)` is described as:

> ```
> 8.4  <in predicate>
>
> [...]
>
> 4) The expression
>      RVC IN IPV
>    is equivalent to
>      RVC = ANY IPV
> ```

And:

> ```
> 8.7  <quantified comparison predicate>
>
> [...]
>
> <quantified comparison predicate> ::=
>      <row value constructor> <comp op> <quantifier> <table subquery>
>
> <quantifier> ::= <all> | <some>
>
> <all> ::= ALL
>
> <some> ::= SOME | ANY
>
> [...]
>
>    c) If the implied <comparison predicate> is true for at least
>      one row RT in T, then "R <comp op> <some> T" is true.
> ```

The last line seems to suggest that `x IN (a, b, c)` is supposed to provide identical result as `x = a OR x = b OR x = c`. However the specs do not dictate how the RDBMs should implement the behavior, it could vary across RDBMs.

This following posts contain some interesting observations:

- [IN vs OR in the SQL WHERE Clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3074713/in-vs-or-in-the-sql-where-clause) (MySQL and other)
- [SQL IN() versus OR](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/204559/sql-in-versus-or) (SQL Server)

SQL Server seems to generate same execution plan for `x IN (...)` and `x = ... OR x = ...` where as MySQL handles them differently.

Comment: For SQL Server have a look at https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2018/06/13/sql-server-performance-comparison-in-vs-or/ and for others have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3074713/in-vs-or-in-the-sql-where-clause. SQL Server simply translates IN to multiple ORs, MySQL handles them differently.

Answer (score 3):

That depends on the database.  Logically, the `IN` is interpreted as a sequence of `OR`s, but that does not mean that is the underlying implementation.

For instance, MySQL will order a list of constants and use a binary search to find a match.  That is quite different from a series of `OR`s.