# Which one is faster in Hive? "in" or "or"?

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hiveql

"in" Example:

```
select * from t where something in ('a', 'b', 'c')
```

"or" Example:

```
select * from t where something='a' or something='b' or something='c'
```

Is there an efficiency difference between these two? Or they are the same under the hood?

Comment: They are going to be pretty much the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends largely on databases and optimizers. Best way to see **explain plan** for both queries. For smaller number of values it does not matter much but as number of values increases then **IN** clause usually outperforms **OR**.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3074713/in-vs-or-in-the-sql-where-clause) has great insight and comparison for different databases for **in** and **or**.

Comment: I'm gonna run some queries to see which one's faster. Thanks.