# Scala slick: filter using "in" on multiple columns

Tags: scala, slick, slick-3.0

Suppose I have the following table structure:

```sql
create table PEOPLE (
    ID integer not null primary key,
    NAME varchar(100) not null
);

create table CHILDREN (
    ID integer not null primary key,
    PARENT_ID_1 integer not null references PERSON (id),
    PARENT_ID_2 integer not null references PERSON (id)
);
```

and that I want to generate a list of the names of each person who is a parent. In slick I can write something like:

```scala
for {
  parent <- people
  child  <- children if {
    parent.id === child.parent_id_1 ||
    parent.id === child.parent_id_2
  }
} yield {
  parent.name
}
```

and this generates the expected SQL:

```sql
select p.name
from people p, children c
where p.id = c.parent_id_1 or p.id = c.parent_id_2
```

However, this is not optimal: the `OR` part of the expression can cause horrendously slow performance in some DBMSes, which end up doing full-table scans to join on `p.id` even though there's an index there (see for example [this bug report for H2](https://github.com/h2database/h2database/issues/320)). The general problem is that the query planner can't know if it's faster to execute each side of the `OR` separately and join the results back together, or simply do a full table scan [2].

I'd like to generate SQL that looks something like this, which then *can* use the (primary key) index as expected:

```sql
select p.name
from people p, children c
where p.id in (c.parent_id_1, c.parent_id_2)
```

My question is: how can I do this in slick? The existing methods don't seem to offer a way:

- [`ColumnExtensionMethods.in`](https://github.com/slick/slick/blob/master/slick/src/main/scala/slick/lifted/ExtensionMethods.scala#L44) takes `Query` as a parameter, but I don't have a `Query` I have a number or `Rep[Long]` for each of my ID columns
- [`ColumnExtensionMethods.inSet`](https://github.com/slick/slick/blob/master/slick/src/main/scala/slick/lifted/ExtensionMethods.scala#L46) is for binding existing (known) literal arrays, not for joining to sets of columns

What I'd like to be able to write is something like this:

```scala
for {
  parent <- people
  child  <- children
  if parent.id in (child.parent_id_1, child.parent_id_2)
} yield {
  p.name
}
```

but that's not possible right now.

[1] My actual design is a little more complex than this, but it boils down to the same problem.

[2] Some DBMSes *do* have this optimisation for simple cases, e.g. [OR-expansion in Oracle](https://blogs.oracle.com/optimizer/optimizer-transformations:-or-expansion).

Comment: If you perform `explain` on the two queries (`OR` versus `IN`), say, in PostgreSQL, you'll see they are essentially the same (both executed with condition `id = c.parent_id_1 OR id = c.parent_id_2`).

Comment: @LeoC it will depend massively on the DBMS of course, but also on the relative sizes of the tables, indexing strategies and so on - so without more information on what test data you were using it's hard to tell if your statement is accurate. 

My point is that, in general, I would expect `p.id in (..., ...)` to be *at least* as fast as `or`, but in many case it can be much faster. Therefore I'd prefer to use `in` where possible.

Comment: This relevant [SO Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3074713/in-vs-or-in-the-sql-where-clause) might be of interest.  One of the answers suggests that if the column is indexed (as in your case), `IN` and `OR` would perform the same in MySQL.  Given that RDBMSes may implement their query optimizer differently, I suppose it'd be best to do some profiling on the actual dataset, schema and RDBMS platform.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this isn't currently (as at slick 3.2.3) possible, so I've [raised an issue on github](https://github.com/slick/slick/issues/1997) and submitted a pull request to add this functionality.