# Multiple IN Clauses in SQL

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I'm not sure about the functionality of the IN clause so I want to know if I can run a query safely. For what I understand when using IN clause in SQL Server creates a series of OR statements:
So for example

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
```

Will be the same that:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column = 1 OR column = 2 OR column = 3 OR column = 4 OR column = 5 OR column = 6
```

But what happens when something like this is executed:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column IN (1, 2, 3) and column2 IN (4,5,6) and column 3 IN (5,7,8)
```

Here I want to know if for example, if some value from the first IN has two occurrences within the second one it will retrieve both results, or if it's executed in order like 1 and 4 and 5 (The first value within the IN clauses)

I want to run a query with 8 parameters that I need to check in the DB (Sending by C#) but I don't want to build a super huge query with a lot of OR like this (because it will be +90k records)

```
 SELECT * FROM table WHERE (column = 1 and column2 = 4 and column3 = 5 ) or 
(column = 2 and column2= 5 and column3 = 7) OR ....
```

Or I don't know if there is a better approach to solve this, I'm open to ideas.

Thanks

Comment: This is a sql (sql server) specific question, not related to c#

Comment: The IN operator is a shorthand for multiple OR conditions.

Comment: The effect of `column in (value1, value2, ...)` is similar to `column = value1 or column = value2 or...` but the performance **is** **not**. Consider using the `IN`. Check this question for further info https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3074713/in-vs-or-in-the-sql-where-clause

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `IN`s are separate conditions, so the logic is equivalent to:

```
where (column1 = 1 or column1 = 2 or column1 = 3) and
      (column2 = 4 or column2 = 5 or column2 = 6)
```

Note that this is a *logical* equivalence.  Some databases optimize `IN` with constant lists, for instance, by creating a binary tree for searching the values.  I don't think that SQL Server does such an optimization though.

If you want "alignment", some databases -- but not SQL Server -- support tuples using `IN`:

```
where (column1, column2) in ( (1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 5) )
```

And this can always be represented as:

```
where (column1 = 1 and column2 = 4) or
      (column1 = 2 and column2 = 5) or
      (column1 = 3 and column2 = 6)
```

Comment: OP mentions sql server explicitly, but the tuples edit is a very nice addition to the answer

Comment: Thanks, I will try to build some large query with multiple OR.