# Finding unique values in table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to find 240 unique values in my table which contains 300.000 rows.

my unique values are like:
elephant,turtle,bird,turkey,snake
(I have list all of them)

I have tried:

```
Where column_name like 'snake'
    or column_name like 'bird'
    or column name like 'snake' etc...
```

but I'm not sure it is a good way to find my values.

Comment: Select DISTINCT ColumnName From YourTableName

Comment: Make it easy, and possible, to assist you - show us some sample table data _and the expected result_ - all as formatted text (not images.) [mcve]

Comment: Your question is still not clear; you want to find all the distinct values, and there are 240 of them, or you want to find only a specific list of those 240 values?

Comment: i want to find specific 240 values from 300.000 in my table

Comment: Where is your list, in a table, the result of another query, or a hard coded list?

Comment: I have list in excel file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to find the row with the values from a list you can do

```
SELECT * FROM animals WHERE name IN ('elephant','cat');
```

Comment: so if i want find all 240 rows with values  i have to make IN ('elephant', 'cat', ... another 240 values) ?

Comment: If you wanne find all the rows who have value elephant,cat, ... you will need to do that.
If you wanne find all unique animals use @Pablo Santa Cruz awnser.

Comment: is any huge difference if I use for example  Where column_name LIKE 'snake'
    or column_name like 'bird'
    or column name like 'snake' ... ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3074713/in-vs-or-in-the-sql-where-clause should awnser your question. Using WHERE IN would also be a lot cleaner

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
> select distinct animal_name from your_300000_table;
```

So, suppose your table is this:

```
> create table animals (
    animal_id numeric(10) primary key,
    animal_type varchar(32) not null, -- here you have snake, bird, you name it
    added_date datetime2,
    location_lat numeric(11,8),
    location_lon numeric(11,8)
  );
> select distinct animal_type from animals;
> -- this will yield the expected result.
```

Comment: `SELECT animal_type, COUNT(animal_id) AS [Animal count] FROM animals GROUP BY animal_type;` will also give you a count of each animal - just a thought.

Comment: Good idea. An index on `animal_type` wouldn't hurt either.