# Differences between OR condition or IN condition in SQL

Tags: sql, conditional-statements, where-clause

I wonder what is the difference in terms of performance or use of resources between a sentence in sql where I have a WHERE sentence of the kind

```
WHERE VALUE IN (A,B,C .......)
```

or

```
WHERE VALUE = A OR VALUE = B OR VALUE = C.....
```

I am wondering this because in an Oracle Query I have to search all the information related with this values. I can not create a temporary table. I just receive them from an external source. First I though I would be as simple as putting them inside the IN clause. The number of values is variable but never lower than 3000. On the other hand I read that there is a limit in Oracle for the quantity of values for kind of conditions, but until now I have never received more than 4000.

Comment: No difference at all

Comment: I suppose this will depend on the type of database software you use. If this is really relevant for you, you should go and measure this with an EXPLAIN statement or alike. Then you will see if the parser does a good job and handles both the same. And: IN has the clear advantage that you could use sub select instead of static values or a variable number of values.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: There's a great discussion of this, including real MySQL performance data at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3074713/in-vs-or-in-the-sql-where-clause

This has also been discussed for Oracle at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6514906/in-vs-or-of-oracle-which-faster

MS SQL Server has been discussed at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2110715/sql-server-select-in-vs-or

Comment: @rob regarding the question in your deleted answer once you get 3k rep you can vote to close as dupe. In absence of info about the RDBMS it is not clear which of those links would be the best target though!

Answer (score 1):

No difference at all. internally DB engine going to flatten that `IN` list to a `OR`ed condition stack like

```
WHERE VALUE IN (A,B,C .......)
```

will get flatten to

```
WHERE VALUE = A OR VALUE = B ...
```

Comment: They haven't told us the DB engine.

Comment: @MartinSmith. that's true but in most RDBMS it's the case; at least so I know of in case of `MySQL`, `SQL Server` and `NETEZZA`

Comment: The link in the other answer shows that in MySQL they are not the same.

Comment: I disagree. Logically they are the same, but in my experience the optimizer doesn't convert it.

Answer (score 0):

They are *logically* the same (in that they produce the same result), but the optimizer will only use an index (if one exists) for one of the values from an OR - effectively *not* using an index (since O(log n) + O(n) = O(n)).

In my experience, when looking for ways to improve query performance, one of the first things I do is convert ORs on a column to a single IN (which usually has a great effect).