# Querying data by multiple ids (large number)

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I want to query data for a set of IDs from a table. The size of the set might become large in some cases, for around 1000 to 4000 IDs.

Ex1: `SELECT x FROM table WHERE id IN (ID1, ID2, ..., ID4000)`

Ex2: `SELECT x FROM table WHERE id = ID1 OR id = ID2 ... OR id  =ID4000`

1- Whats the limitation of including such a set in the query's `WHERE` clause (`OR` or `IN` statement)?

2- Is there a drawback or is that size considered large?

3- Is splitting the query to smaller portions the alternative?

Comment: The answer is implementation defined. Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Such limits depend on the database you are using.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "_SQL_" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Answer (score 0):

This link below will help you to think which is better to use.

Maybe, first of all, you should tell me what database you Are using.

MySQL : 
[IN vs OR in the SQL WHERE Clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3074713/in-vs-or-in-the-sql-where-clause)

SQL Server : 
[SQL Server: Select in vs or?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2110715/sql-server-select-in-vs-or)

PostgreSQL : 
https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/8078a1730712121530r70a520e1qf9c09b516db54b0e%40mail.gmail.com